# Экранирование полей JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Есть JSON со сложной структурой, у которого в значении поля есть символ кавычек или другой спец. символ. Как экранировать этот символ во внутренней строке, игнорируя кавычки названия полей, начала и конца значения?

Т.е. привести такой вид JSON:

```
      {"Model":{"Id":13900954,"Name":"Смартфон Apple iPhone 5S
 16GB","Description":"Экран: 4" 640x1136 • Стандарт связи: 3G, ","Vendor":"Apple","VendorId":165}
```

к такому:

```
      {"Model":{"Id":13900954,"Name":"Смартфон Apple iPhone 5S
 16GB","Description":"Экран: 4\" 640x1136 • Стандарт связи: 3G, ","Vendor":"Apple","VendorId":165}
```

*отличие в поле Description. Экранируется кавычка после цифры 4

Comment: вы генерирует это JSON или получаете откуда-то?

Comment: Первый пример у вас НЕ json. Используйте инструменты, которые понимают json формат — они сами, когда нужно заэкранируют и кавычки и другие специальные символы. Не стоит руками свой json сериализатор писать.

Comment: @jfs это кусок вырезанный для понимания того что мне нужно. Я получаю с MAILRU API json. Его и надо распарсить в программе. Юзаю для этого JSONObject  и т.д

Comment: @АксеновВладимир "экранизация" и "экранирование" - это сильно разные по значению слова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json выше невалиден. Таким образом:

Как экранировать этот символ во внутренней строке, игнорируя кавычки названия полей, начала и конца значения?
Ответ: никак. Необходимо менять саму json строку